# Closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ projecting to rationals

Tags: general-topology

Let $\pi\colon \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be the projection to the first coordinate. Does there exist a closed set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ s.t. $\pi[C] = \mathbb{Q}$? (And in general where $\mathbb{Q}$ is replaced by any $F_\sigma$ set.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $q_1, q_2, \ldots$ be an enumeration of the rationals.  Then $$\{\langle q_n, n\rangle\}$$ is a closed set whose projection is $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: The funny thing about this construction is that it's a transfinite induction argument without the transfinite induction.

Comment: I'm curious what you mean by your comment.

Answer (score 2):

As $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, define $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\mathbb{Q}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{x_n\}.$ Then take $C=\{(x_n,n)\,;\, n\in\mathbb{N}\}.$ Note that each point of $C$ is isolated, then $C$ is closed. Finally, observe that $$\pi(C)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{\pi(x_n,n)\}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{x_n\}=\mathbb{Q}.$$ I let you find a similar argument for the $F_\sigma.$

Answer (score 1):

For an $F_\sigma$ set $F = \cup_n C_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Define $G = \cup_n(F_n \times \{n\})$, then $G$ is closed, and $\pi_1[G] = F$.